# Complex Matrix Inversion with GSL

Tags: c, linear-algebra, gsl, matrix-inverse

I am in the middle of porting prototype matlab code into C, and have hit a hitch on inverting a nxn matrix of complex numbers.

I am using GSL to perform LU decompositon and inversion with the following code:

```
size_t matSize = 4;
gsl_permutation *perm = gsl_permutation_calloc(matSize);
gsl_matrix_complex *mat = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(matSize, matSize);
gsl_matrix_complex *inv = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(matSize, matSize);

gsl_complex temp;
for(int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < matSize; j++) {
        GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&temp,i+1,j+1);
        gsl_matrix_complex_set(mat,i,j,temp);
    }
}

int s;
gsl_linalg_complex_LU_decomp(mat, perm, &s);
gsl_linalg_complex_LU_invert(mat, perm, inv);

for(int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
        printf("%f + %fi \n",GSL_REAL(gsl_matrix_complex_get(inv, i, j)),GSL_IMAG(gsl_matrix_complex_get(inv, i, j)));
    }
}
```

However comparing the results I get to matlab, they are not similar at all.  I know matlab does not always use LU for inversion as it has an algorithm decision tree depending on matrix properties, but I would expect comparable results.

Any help welcomed. As well as recommendations for other libraries / techniques of inversion (not that GSL is wrong, without a doubt I am!) the matrix I have is type fftw_complex and I would rather avoid converting too/from gsl_complex_matrix.

Comment: Can you share the matrix you’re inverting? I’m wondering if it’s singular and that’s why Matlab disagrees with GSL. You can also ask Matlab for just the `lu` factorization to compare to GSL’s LU.

Comment: The matrix I am inverting is hidden in the code I provided, its procedurally generated to make comparing matlab and C a little easier.

`for(int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < matSize; j++) {
        GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&temp,i+1,j+1);
        gsl_matrix_complex_set(mat,i,j,temp);
    }
}`

Comparing LU decomposition in Matlab vs GSL, they are comparable. The only issue is when the exponents get super small (around -16) in C they are rounded to 0.